# Using Assert containing wildcards (Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, assert

I'm trying to use webdriver to check that something DOESN'T exist on the webpage (after it has been deleted by the user).

I'm using a try-catch method to handle the `NoSuchElementException`, but within the 'catch' I want to be able to assert that the NoSuchElementException contains the text "NoSuchElementException", and use wildcards for the rest of the exception (since other details within the exception change every time)

Here's what the bit of code looks like, as you can see I've tried to use a * as a wild card to indicate that nothing after the exception matters to me, I just want it to check that the exception is the correct one and pass the test based on that:

```
catch (NoSuchElementException e1)
{
    Assert.assertEquals(e1, "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: *");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are catching `NoSuchElementException` and inside the catch block you are checking if it is a `NoSuchElementException` which does not add any value. You are testing if JDK works correctly.

To check if the element does not exist on page, you could use a method like this :

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By locatorKey) {
    try {
          driver.findElement(locatorKey);
          return true;
        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
          return false;
        }
}
```

You should then assert on the above method,

if element should not be present

```
Assert.assertFalse(isElementPresent(By.id("login")));
```

if element should be present

```
Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("login")));
```

Comment: Thanks LINGS this is really helpful, I have responded in the form of an answer with a few questions. (I'm not a developer so still learning)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using TestNG assertions. If so, I would use `contains` to search for a partial match.

```
assertTrue(e1.getClass().toString.contains("org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:"));
```

Comment: should it be assertTrue(e1.toString().contains("org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:")) ? or e1.getClass().toString.contains...